# How to omit group separators in the decimal part when using siunitx?

Tags: siunitx

That's my MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{book}

\usepackage[load=addn,separate-uncertainty=true]{siunitx}

\sisetup{%
      output-decimal-marker={,},
      load-configurations=abbreviations,
      group-separator={.},
      per-mode=fraction
    }

\begin{document}
    \SI{12345.66666666}{\kilo\meter\per\hour}
\end{document}
```

The result has been being `12.345,666.666.66`, but I want `12.345,66666666`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The `group-digits` option is a choice key, which has the possible values `true,false,integer` or `decimal`. In this case, only the integer part of the number should have group digits, so use `group-digits=integer`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{book}

\usepackage[load=addn,separate-uncertainty=true]{siunitx}

\sisetup{%
      output-decimal-marker={,},
      load-configurations=abbreviations,
      group-separator={.},
      per-mode=fraction,
      group-digits=integer
    }

\begin{document}
    \SI{12345.66666666}{\kilo\meter\per\hour}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Updated due to the comment**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{book}

\usepackage[separate-uncertainty=true]{siunitx}

\sisetup{%
  output-decimal-marker={,},
  group-separator={.},
  group-minimum-digits=4,
  per-mode=fraction,
  group-digits=integer
}

\begin{document}
\num{62034.023458763e23} 


\num{6232.023458763e23} 

\SI{12345.66666666}{\kilo\meter\per\hour}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi. It works well with  with 6 integers digits, example: \num{62034.023458763e23} but not with 5. Try     \num{6203.023458763e23}. Is it a bug?

Comment: @cbe-user-99263: No, it is no bug, it is  by - design. `sunitx` does not group  digits fewer than 5 by default -- if this not wanted, use `group-minimum-digits=4, for example, as the updated example